# FFMPEG - Download video in parts and concat, stutter at concat points

Tags: ffmpeg

My goal is to **download** a video (or M3U8) **in parts/chunks** which I can **later concat**.

For context, I would like to download videos in an Android Service which may be stopped at any time, so I think chunking is the right approach.

After some time I got the "**downloading the parts**" right, **using this**. I would later put that in a function, and for now I chose the chunks to be 30 seconds long.

```
%offset% = 30 * %part%

ffmpeg -ss %offset% -t 30 -i INPUT_FILE -avoid_negative_ts 1 out%part%.mp4
```

The first line is just pseudocode, part is starting at 0.
This works fine, downloading 30 second long .mp4 files.

After that I tried merging them together into a single .mp4. For the tests I only downloaded the first few parts.

**Concat command:**

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy final.mp4
```

This would be a very short **concat.txt file:**

```
file 'out0.mp4'
file 'out1.mp4'
```

The concat works but has one problem: At the point where both files are actually combined, so **at 30 seconds**, there is a **small stutter** in video and audio.

So what I think is going on is that I download parts that are 30s long, starting at multiples of 30s so there is a small overlap? In the "Details" part of the Windows file properties it also shows a length of **31 seconds**, so the video is even longer than I want.

I tried **setting the duration** of each part in the **concat.txt**, both to 30s and to 30s - 1 frame

```
23.98 fps -> 1/23.98 spf = 0.0417s
```

But with a duration of 30 as well as 29.9583, although it is **better**, there is **still a small stutter**.

```
file 'out0.mp4'
duration 29.9583
file 'out1.mp4'
duration 29.9583
```

I also tried with a different fileformat, .ts files, but the stutter was still there. I still think my timings are not quite right, but at this point I don't know where the problem is exactly. **What do I need to change to remove the small stutter?**

Comment: The main problem imho is in downloading. Have you consider download the full video at once and use ‘segment’ muxer to store downloaded video as separate files?

Comment: @kesh Downloading the whole video is not really an option for me. I started writing my own chunked downloader for the mp4 file which I can binary concat. As for the m3u8 download, I will probably just download the highest quality segments and use FFMPEG to concat them. That lets FFFMPEG work with the segments that are meant to be in that length.

I would still like to know how this can be solved, although I will probably not use it directly anmore.